# Is it recommended to use hashcode to determine equality in Java?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Let's say we have a `hashcode()` function, which will then be used inside our `equals()` method to determine the equality of two objects. Is this an allowed/accepted approach?

Assume that we use a simple implementation of a hash code. (For example a few instance variables multiplied by prime numbers.)

Comment: Is comparing hashCode the only thing you plan to do in there? Or just one of several steps?

Comment: I am not planning to use it, I just wanted to throw the idea out there since my instructor at uni simply said "don't do it" but couldn't explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a terrible way to check for equality, mostly since Objects don't have to be equal to return the same hashcode.

You should always use the equals method for this.

The general rule is:

> If the equals method returns true for Objects a and b, the hashCode
>   method must return the same value for a and b.
>
> This does not mean, that if the hashCode method for a and b returns
>   the same value, the equals method has to return true for these two
>   instances.

for instance:

```
public int hashCode(){
  return 5;
}
```

is a valid, though be it inefficiënt, hashcode implementation.

EDIT:

to use it within an equals method would be something like this:

```
public class Person{

private String name;

public Person(String name){ this.name = name;}

public String getName(){ return this.name;}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
  if ( !(o instanceof Person)){ return false;}
  Person p = (Person)o;
  boolean nameE = this.name == null ? p.getName() == null : this.name.equals(p.getName());
  boolean hashE = nameE ? true : randomTrueOrFalse();
  // the only moment you're sure hashE is true, is if the previous check returns true.
  // in any other case, it doesn't matter whether they are equal or not, since the nameCheck returns false, so in best case, it's redundant
  return nameE && hashE;
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
  int hash = generateValidHashCode();
  return hash;
}

}
```

Comment: True, two objects that are not equal might have the same hash, but chances are slim by a wide margin. Say SHA-256 is used to find the hash. SHA-256 provides 2^256 possible values of the hash of any given object, right? This implies there is a 1/2^256 chance of having the same hash.

Comment: @the_prole you are now assuming SHA-256 is commonly used in hashCode methods.
I've worked on projects as professional developer for over a decade, I've never seen it in a production environment.

Comment: I see. So for hash code method, we cannot assume same collision resistance as SHA-256?

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad practice. Hashes are supposed to have a minimal amount of collisions, but usually you have more possibilities for objects than the amount of possible hashes and because of the pigeonhole principle a few distinct objects must have the same hash.

When comparing hashes, you have a certain chance of getting "false positives".

Answer (score 1):

**Actually, it is not a bad idea!**

But make sure you use this method to determine inequality, not equality. Hashing code may be faster than checking equality, especially when hashcode is stored (for example in `java.lang.String`).

If two object have different hashcodes they **must be** different, else they **may be** the same. For example you may use this method as the following

```
Object a, b;
if(a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()){
    if(a.equals(b)) return true;
}

return false;
```

Be aware that in some cases code above may be slower than using only `equals()`, especially when in most cases `a` does equal `b`.

From documentation of `Object.java`:

> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Comment: If you are caching hashCodes this is a good optimization. Otherwise, calculating the hashCode is probably slower than comparing all the fields that go into it.

Comment: Since this might cause false positives, I wouldn't really call it "not a bad idea". It would only be valid if you add it as an additional check, but then basically what you are doing is: if ( allIsTrue && (allIsTrue || somethingSimilar)) so, basically: allIsTrue already answered the question

Comment: If this is really an optimisation then you should expect the `equals` method to already be doing it. So either way you should just call `equals`.

Comment: @kaya3 Note that the question was stated from the point of actually _writing_ the `equals` method. Also sometimes optimizations happen under some specific circumstances, so it might not make sense to add them to `equals` for everyone

Comment: If you wrote this inside the `equals` method then it would have unbounded recursion for objects with the same hashCode, since it calls the `equals` method itself.

Comment: The code snippet from this answer was meant to give an idea of how this might work and should be treated rather as a pseudo code (you could also argue that `a` and `b` are uninitialized). When using this idea specifically inside `equals`, of course you would have to change the equality check to the actual implementation (or other method call), the same way you would change `a` to `this` and `b` to `other`.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do this**

While it is correct that you need to override equals() and hashCode() in pairs, having the same hash is not the same as having the same values.

Put some effort into really thinking the equality thing through. Don't shortcut here **it will bite you later**.